# TCP: Disable pure ACKs?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have a scenario where I wish to disable pure ACKs (TCP ACKs with no data), but I can't find how to do this. Is there an option that I can set so that ACKs are always piggybacked onto the next data packet (of which I can be sure that it will come)?

I tried disabling quickACKs via the `ip route` commando for a specific network range and device, but it didn't seem to have any effect. 
As additional info, I'm running a 4.4 kernel on this maschine. If you need more info, ask and I shall provide.

Answer (score 1):

A packet has to be ACKnowledged by the recipient within a specific time because otherwise the sender assumes that the packet got lost and will retransmit it. If your recipient sends data anyway the ACK will be added to these data. If no data are sent then a pure ACK need to be send to let the sender know on time that the packet was received.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I'm very sure that the data is send within the timeframe (500ms I think?) I'll take a look again to confirm that this is not the reason why it's sending pure ACKs but I really don't believe it is.
Edit: I looked at my PCAP, it does send the regular data much earlier than needed, so the problem should not be a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the application that was giving me these pure ACKs used a socket with the TCP_NODELAY option set, so every packet would be answered as soon as possible without waiting for additional data.